# Parallizing the calculation of an integral

Tags: c, math, parallel-processing, mpi

Here I have a piece of code that is a function to calculate an integral of a function. In the code is function() defined as the function to integrate.

I'm learning about parallel programming and I need to write this code in parallel. The original program is sequential, because every iteration a send operation is done to another processor. What I want to achieve to make it parallel, is that each loop iteration 3 send operations are executed to the other 3 available processors. Imagine 1 processor who divides the tasks (rank = 0) and 3 other processors who do the actual calculation.

Beware it is a large piece of code, but I also included comments to make it more clear:

**The sequential code:**

```
    if (myRank == 0)
    {
        // I am the controller, distribute the work
        for (step = 0; step < maxSteps; step++)
        {
            x[0] = x_start + stepSize*step;
            x[1] = x_start + stepSize*(step+1);
            nextRank = step % (numProcs-1) + 1;
            // Send the work
            MPI_Send(x, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, nextRank, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            // Receive the result
            MPI_Recv(y, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, nextRank, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            sum += stepSize*0.5*(y[0]+y[1]);
        }
        // Signal workers to stop by sending empty messages with tag TAG_END
        for (nextRank = 1; nextRank < numProcs; nextRank++)
            MPI_Send(&nextRank, 0, MPI_INT, nextRank, TAG_END, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            // I am a worker, wait for work

            // Receive the left and right points of the trapezoid and compute
            // the corresponding function values. If the tag is TAG_END, don't
            // compute but exit.
            MPI_Recv(x, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                &status);
            if (status.MPI_TAG == TAG_END) break;
            y[0] = f(x[0]);
            y[1] = f(x[1]);
            // Send back the computed result
            MPI_Send(y, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

To parallelize it, I really hard-coded it, to make clear what I do. I made the loop increment with steps of 3. I added new arrays to store the x- and y-values. What I did was first collect the x-values in a specific array. Then I send each array of x values to a new processor. Then I execute the other function to obtain the y-values. Then I send them back to processor (rank = 0) to add all the 'integration slices'.

**The tried to parallelized code**

```
 if (myRank == 0)
    {
        // I am the controller, distribute the work
        for (step = 0; step < maxSteps; step+3)
        {
            x1[0] = x_start + stepSize*step;
            x1[1] = x_start + stepSize*(step+1);
            x2[0] = x_start + stepSize*(step+1);
            x2[1] = x_start + stepSize*((step+1)+1);
            x3[0] = x_start + stepSize*(step+2);
            x3[1] = x_start + stepSize*((step+1)+2);
            nextRank = step % (numProcs-1) + 1;
            // Send the work
            MPI_Send(x1, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(x2, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 2, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(x3, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 3, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            // Receive the result
            MPI_Recv(y1, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            sum += stepSize*0.5*(y1[0]+y1[1]);
            MPI_Recv(y2, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 2, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            sum += stepSize*0.5*(y2[0]+y2[1]);
            MPI_Recv(y3, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 3, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            sum += stepSize*0.5*(y3[0]+y3[1]);
        }
        // Signal workers to stop by sending empty messages with tag TAG_END
        for (nextRank = 1; nextRank < numProcs; nextRank++)
            MPI_Send(&nextRank, 0, MPI_INT, nextRank, TAG_END, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (myRank = 1)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            MPI_Recv(x1, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            if (status.MPI_TAG == TAG_END) break;
            y1[0] = func(x1[0]);
            y1[1] = func(x1[1]);
            // Send back the computed result
            MPI_Send(y1, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    
    else if (myRank = 2)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            MPI_Recv(x2, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            if (status.MPI_TAG == TAG_END) break;
            y2[0] = func(x2[0]);
            y2[1] = func(x2[1]);
            // Send back the computed result
            MPI_Send(y2, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    
    else if (myRank = 3)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            MPI_Recv(x3, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            if (status.MPI_TAG == TAG_END) break;
            y3[0] = func(x3[0]);
            y3[1] = func(x3[1]);
            // Send back the computed result
            MPI_Send(y3, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, TAG_WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The problem is that I don't get output anymore. I'm afraid I created a deadlock, but I can't discover where. Could I get feedback on this method?

source: https://doc.itc.rwth-aachen.de/display/VE/PPCES+2012

Comment: the code looks legit, please provide your `mpirun` command line and a [MCVE] since the deadlock might hide somewhere else. As a matter of style, you can simply `MPI_Bcast(x_start, ..._` and then `MPI_Reduce(y, ...)`. Also, rank `0` can invoke `func()` instead of sitting idle waiting for the other ranks.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator in C. Use `==` to check equailty.

Comment: Also `step+3` in the `for` statement will do nothing.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to satisfy my curiosity and let me know where did you obtain the original code from? I'm asking because it dates back to 2012 and is from the MPI part of [PPCES 2012](https://doc.itc.rwth-aachen.de/display/VE/PPCES+2012) - an annual tutorial for users of the RWTH Aachen University's cluster. Most of the code logic comes from others before me, but the code clean-up and the long comments are definitely mine... BTW, the answer to your question is in the solutions that should be available at the PPCES website. Same applies to some of your other questions about MPI :-)

Comment: @Hristolliev Yes, I'm a student from the TU Delft of technology. Currently I'm enrollend in the minor computational science and engieering. This assignment is part of the course 'parallel computing'. I didn't know that the material was yours. I just dowloaded it from our course site. I edited the post with the link of the website!

Comment: Nice to hear that others find the materials from PPCES useful. I hope your instructor(s) gave the guys at RWTH a hat tip as they are doing the community a great service by making all materials available to anyone on the Internet.

Comment: A question about the topic:

In the code from my post I labeled as sequential the problem was I thought that in each interation a task is assigned to a new processor.  My instructor gave away as hint that you have to get rid of the sequential execution. So I thought "What if I send each iteration a task to all processors?" In part 1 of your code two things I don't understand. 

1/2

Comment: -  The execution time goes down as the number of P increases with your code, with the sequential code it doesn't (logical!) In part 1 I see a loop that in each iteration assigns a task. So what is in essence different from the sequential version in the parallel version?

- In part 1  the loop condition step < numProcs-1 && step < maxSteps. I don't understand how you will get the whole domain [0,1] with this condition? Because if np = 4, that means that step will be 0, 1, 2. I don't see how you get futher than x_start+3*Stepsize.

2/2

Comment: @hristolliev Sorry for the many questions, but due to corona we can't go to university. I'm really lost with parallel programming

Comment: The problem of the original code is that each time a work item is sent to a worker rank, the controller waits to get the result back before sending out another work item. This is no different than sequential execution, just the computation gets offloaded to a different rank. You need to modify it in such way as to allow several ranks to work on work items simultaneously and leave no idle gaps. Sending tasks to all ranks in each iteration will make things only slightly better since faster ranks will still have to wait for the slowest one in the current iteration.

Comment: A typical implementation of this "controller-worker" pattern (formerly known as "master-slave") is for the controller to send out initially tasks to all workers and then enter a loop in which it listens for results from any worker rank. Once it receives a result, the controller checks if there are more work items to process and if so it sends a new work item to the same worker that it received the result from. If no more work, the controller sends a stop message.

Comment: _"In part 1 the loop condition step < numProcs-1 && step < maxSteps. I don't understand how you will get the whole domain [0,1] with this condition?"_ - You don't. It's the job of the next part, which continues sending out new tasks to workers that have completed their task until the entire integration domain is covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get profit of having 8 cores (this is an example only) the best thing you can do (and the simplest) is to divide your integral interval in eight parts (you can make the partition arbitrarily, to give each the same amount of work, that's up to you) and then calculate independently each integral (with the same loop you had for one thread) in each thread.

This approach doesn't change you original calculation and makes the calculations completely independent from each other (so there's no contention of resources at all)

Finally you only have to add the eight integrals to obtain the result you want.

If you are thinking on things like unrolling loops to make more parallelism then you had better to trust your compiler, which is capable to use in parallel his optimizer to get profit of the more than 32 registers a normal cpu has today, and you most probably won't do it better.

The approach suggested here converts your integral in 8 different integral calculations, each with different parameters and different values, and the calculus in one thread doesn't depend on the calculus on others, so, even in a threading core based on pipelines, you'll never have to reorder or complicate instructions because it's very easy to add instructions of another thread to the pipeline in order to not make bubbles.  If you have 8 cores, actually more than 8 threads calculating something doesn't represent any advantageous task.